# Problems trying to run a custom SFTP service on port 22 on Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have build a Node.js app that implements an SFTP server; when files are `put` to the server, the app parses the data and loads it into a Salesforce instance via API as it arrives.  The app runs in a Docker container, and listens on port 9001.  I'd like it run on Amazon's EC2 Container Service, listening on standard port 22.  I can run it locally, remapping 9001 to host 22, and it works fine.  But because 22 is also used by SSH, I'm not having any luck running it on ECS.  Here are the steps I've taken so far:

- Created an EC2 instance using the AMI `amzn-ami-2016.03.j-amazon-ecs-optimized (ami-562cf236)`.
- Assigned the instance to a Security Group that allows port 22 (was already present).
- Created an ECR registry and pushed my Docker image up to it.
- Created an ECS Task Definition for the image, which contains a port mapping from host port 22 to container port 9001
- Created a service for the task and associated to the Default ECS Cluster, which contains my EC2 instance.

At this point, which viewing the "Events" tab of the Service view, I see the following error:

> service sfsftp_test_service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance XXXX is already using a port required by your task. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section.

I assumed that this is because my Task Definition is trying to map host port 22 which is reserved for SSH, so I tried creating a new version of the Task Definition that maps 9001 to 9001.  I also updated my security group to allow port 9001 access.  This task was started on my instance, and I was able to connect and upload files.  So at this point I know that my Node.js app and the Docker instance are correct.  It's a port mapping issue.

In trying to resolve the port mapping issue, I found [this stackoverflow question about running SSH on an alternate port on EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475303/running-ssh-on-amazon-ec2-instance-on-port-other-than-22), and used the answer there to change my sshd to run on port 9022.  I also updated the Security Group to allow traffic on port 9022.  This worked; I can now SSH to port 9022, and I can no longer ssh to port 22.

However, I'm still getting the `The closest matching container-instance XXXX is already using a port required` error.  I also tried editing the Security Group, changing the default port 22 grant from "SSH" to "Custom TCP Rule", but that change doesn't stick; I'm also not convinced that it's anything but a quick way to pick the right port.

When I view the Container instance from the Cluster screen, I can see that 5 ports are "registered", including port 22:

[image: registered ports screenshot]

According to [this resolved ECS Agent github issue](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/332#issuecomment-194489605), those ports are "reserved by default" by the ECS Agent.  I'm guessing this is why ECS refuses to start my Docker image on the EC2 Instance.  So is this configurable?  Can I "unreserve" port 22 to allow my Docker image to run?

**Edit** to add:  After reviewing [this ECS Agent documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_PortMapping.html#API_PortMapping_Contents), I've opened [an issue on the ECS Agent Github](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/551) as well.